# Run Sqlite in python give me [HY000] error

Tags: python, sqlite

Greeting all,

I have this sqlite query, which is run as expected in sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE 'Time_node1'
AS
SELECT no,
LAG(p.Time) OVER(ORDER BY p.no) PreviousValue,
    p.Time,
    LEAD(p.Time) OVER(ORDER BY p.no) NextValue
FROM table1 p
WHERE SourceName = 'node1'
```

I need to run this query multiple time in python but that gives me an error

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE 'Time_node1' AS SELECT no,LAG(p.Time) OVER(ORDER BY p.no) PreviousValue, p.Time,LEAD(p.Time) OVER(ORDER BY p.no) NextValue FROM table2 p WHERE SourceName = 'node1'")
```

The error

```
Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] near "(": syntax error (1) (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Any help will be very appreciated

Comment: `CREATE TABLE 'Time_node1'` => `CREATE TABLE Time_node1`

Comment: thanks, but that did not solve the problem.@LukaszSzozda